# using Tuleap with Subversion

Tags: svn, tuleap

When I use Tuleap with subversion and when under the application subversion I click on the 'Mes commit SVN' the result is Ok but when i clic on the 'Afficher l'arbre SVN' I obtain the message 'import viewc File "/usr/share/viewvc/lib/viewvc.py/, line 62, in import include File "/usr/share/tuleap/src/www/.../utls/include.py/, line 45, in load_local_config exe'

My version of Tukeap is '7.11.99.544' and this seems to be a Recurring bug.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [known bug](https://tuleap.net/plugins/tracker/?aid=7926) introduced during development of 8.0

You should update your platform